# Android Open AlertDialog from Navigation Drawer

Tags: android, navigation-drawer, android-alertdialog

I am using `NavigationDrawer` with some dummy `Fragments` in the menu and a `AlertDialog`. When I click to open the `AlertDialog` from the drawer I can close it with the no button but when I click to open it again it does not want to.

I must then 1st switch to one of the other fragments in the drawer and then click on the dialog to open it.

How to open it again after you close it without 1st switching to another menu item.

MainActivity.java

```
@Override
public boolean onNavigationItemSelected(MenuItem menuItem) {

    switch (menuItem.getItemId()) {
        case R.id.drawer_fragment_one:
            if (!menuItem.isChecked()) {
                selectedIndex = COLLAPSING_TOOLBAR;
                menuItem.setChecked(true);
                getSupportFragmentManager().beginTransaction().replace(R.id.fragment_container,
                        new FragmentTabOne(), COLLAPSING_TOOLBAR_FRAGMENT_TAG).commit();
            }
            drawerLayout.closeDrawer(GravityCompat.START);
            return true;

        case R.id.drawer_fragment_two:
            if (!menuItem.isChecked()) {
                selectedIndex = COLLAPSING_TOOLBAR;
                menuItem.setChecked(true);
                getSupportFragmentManager().beginTransaction().replace(R.id.fragment_container,
                        new FragmentTabTwo(), COLLAPSING_TOOLBAR_FRAGMENT_TAG).commit();
            }
            drawerLayout.closeDrawer(GravityCompat.START);
            return true;

        case R.id.drawer_alert_dialog:
            if (!menuItem.isChecked()) {
                selectedIndex = ALERT_DIALOG;
                menuItem.setChecked(true);

                final AlertDialog.Builder dialog = new AlertDialog.Builder(MainActivity.this);
                dialog.setIcon(R.mipmap.ic_launcher);
                dialog.setTitle(R.string.app_name);
                dialog.setMessage(R.string.dialog_msg);
                dialog.setPositiveButton(R.string.dialog_option_yes, new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
                    @Override
                    public void onClick(DialogInterface dialogInterface, int i) {

                    }
                });

                dialog.setNegativeButton(R.string.dialog_option_no, new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
                    @Override
                    public void onClick(DialogInterface dialogInterface, int i) {
                        dialogInterface.dismiss();
                    }
                });

                dialog.show();

            }
            drawerLayout.closeDrawer(GravityCompat.START);
            return true;

        }
    return false;
}
```

Comment: Unclear, at least to me: do you want the `Dialog` _before_ switching `Fragment`?

Comment: Why you checked for `if (!menuItem.isChecked())`?

Answer (score 1):

I think when you click the first time on the item that handles the dialog you set checked to true, and when you try to click the second time you test if is not checked, which return false and as consequence your dialog is not shown

Comment: That is the correct answer that explain your main issue: your condition `if (!menuItem.isChecked())` will always be false the other time arounds.

Answer (score 1):

In the below code snippet:

```
case R.id.drawer_alert_dialog:
        if (!menuItem.isChecked()) {
            selectedIndex = ALERT_DIALOG;
            menuItem.setChecked(true);

            final AlertDialog.Builder dialog = new AlertDialog.Builder(MainActivity.this);
            dialog.setIcon(R.mipmap.ic_launcher);
            dialog.setTitle(R.string.app_name);
            dialog.setMessage(R.string.dialog_msg);
            dialog.setPositiveButton(R.string.dialog_option_yes, new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
                @Override
                public void onClick(DialogInterface dialogInterface, int i) {

                }
            });

            dialog.setNegativeButton(R.string.dialog_option_no, new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
                @Override
                public void onClick(DialogInterface dialogInterface, int i) {
                    dialogInterface.dismiss();
                    .... (Add the line here)
                }
            });

            dialog.show();

        }
        drawerLayout.closeDrawer(GravityCompat.START);
        return true;
```

Add the below line, Hopefully this must work:

```
menuItem.setChecked(false);
```

Add it where I've mentioned (Add the line here)